# idx2numpy convert_from_file function returns integer array, but I want float array

Tags: python, numpy

### Introduction

I am starting to study machine learning and have been set the famous MNIST number recognition challenge. I am trying to implement a neural network to achieve this, and I have successfully made it load an image from the dataset. No neural networks are implemented yet.

### Issue

I extracted the image from the dataset using idx2numpy, and want a grey scale image. I used the sigmoid function to turn the provided greyscale image (0-256) into values between 0-1, but it only returns an array of only ones and zeros. I would need floats for the neural network, so this is an issue. Not sure if it is idx2numpy's issue, or the matrix multiplication in the function `multiply_weights(a,w)`.

### Code

```py
import numpy as np
import idx2numpy
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# sigmoid function for activating next layer neurons
def sigmoid(n):
    num_base = 1+(math.e**(n*-1))
    return float(1/num_base)


def sigmoid_2d_arr(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        for j in range(len(arr[i])):
            arr[i][j] = sigmoid(arr[i][j])
    return arr


def sum_2d(arr):
    count = 0
    for i in arr:
        count += sum(i)
    return count


# open files and read files as arrays
labels_file = "train-labels.idx1-ubyte"
images_file = "train-images.idx3-ubyte"

labels_data = np.array(idx2numpy.convert_from_file(labels_file))
images_data = np.array(idx2numpy.convert_from_file(images_file))


# test print an image and its label
def test_print(n):
    image = sigmoid_2d_arr(images_data[n])
    print("Label: " + str(labels_data[n]))
    plt.imshow(image, cmap="gray")
    plt.show()
    print(images_data.shape)


test_print(np.random.randint(0, len(images_data)))


# initialize weights and biases for all neurons
def init_params():
    w1 = np.random.rand(28, 28)
    b1 = np.zeros((28, 28))
    return w1, b1


w1, b1 = init_params()
print(w1)


def multiply_weights(a, w):
    print(a)
    arr = np.dot(a, w)
    return arr


image = sigmoid_2d_arr(images_data[5])
print(sigmoid(sum_2d(multiply_weights(image, w1))))
```

Comment: After creating `image_data`, print out `image_data.dtype`. What does it say?

Comment: @jared it says uint8

Comment: @jared Thanks a lot, I realised I have to specify the dtype for the array to accept floats. Just need to test forward propagation to see if it functions correctly.

Comment: BTW, doing sigmoid is probably not the intended way to convert from integer to float. You're probably intended to do this transformation by converting the dtype, then dividing by 255 rather than applying the sigmoid function. Sigmoid will give you numbers between 0.5-1.0 and apply a nonlinear transformation which will make it hard to distinguish the difference between a pixel with value 128 from one with value 255. (e.g. e^-128 is very very close to e^-255.)

Comment: @Nick ODell I applied a negative weight to the sigmoidified pixel value and then tried to find the sum of the weighted value and then added the bias. This gave the neuron value at position n, and then I apply sigmoid again to that value to find value of a neuron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your image data is being stored as an integer data type rather than float. So, when you run the sigmoid function, you're only getting integer results. To fix this, you can tell numpy what data type to use for `image_data` by passing `dtype=np.float64` (or `np.float32` if you don't need 64-bit floating-point precision).

In brief, change the `image_data` line to:

```py
images_data = np.array(idx2numpy.convert_from_file(images_file), dtype=np.float64)
```